# Masonry/infinite scroll on contained tumblr theme not working? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: infinite-scroll, masonry

I'm trying to create a contained theme that has two columns and has infinite scrolling but it won't do either.

```
$(function(){ 

  var container = $('#content');

  container.imagesLoaded( function(){
    container.masonry({
       itemSelector : '.posts'
    }); 
  });

    container.infinitescroll({<br>
    navSelector  : '.pagin',   
    nextSelector : '.pagin a',
    itemSelector : '.posta',
    loading: {
      finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
      img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
    }
  }, function( newElements ) {

    var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });

    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
      $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
      container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
    });

  }); 

});
```

Example: http://asdfghjklbnmqwertyuiop.tumblr.com/

Everything seems to be in the right place from all the tutorials Do I need to do something differently because it is a contained theme?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please isolate the code relating to masonry and infinite scroll. You are more likely to get a response.

Comment: Can you link to the site showing the issue? I am 99% sure you `itemSelector` on both masonry / infinite scroll are incorrect. They should be the same.

Comment: @mikedidthis Oops, I didn't see the typo! I changed both to ".posts" and nothing changed. The theme is asdfghjklbnmqwertyuiop.tumblr.com. I want to make it so that it's two columns of posts,

Comment: Can you add a link to the site with the issue, I still believe the markup / selectors are incorrect.

Comment: i fixed it. that was a typo, it's supposed to be ".posts" but nothing changed. this is the site: htp://asdfghjklbnmqwertyuiop.tumblr.com I want it so that there's two columns that are infinite scroll.

Comment: Looked at the site, you don't include the script for `imagesLoaded`, the error is in the console. As @riverbell mentioned you don't have an element `.pagin`. Again, this is a set up issue / lack of understanding.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I understand now. The masonry is now working... but the infinite scroll isn't. From what I can see, I'm not missing anything. http://pastebin.com/eyxMAghX

Comment: @mikedidthis oops forgot to tag you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `navselector` is `.pagin` but you don't have a class with that name, you have an `pagin` id in your HTML. Take a look at the `navselector` and make sure it points at the correct element.

Comment: I changed it, still not working. this is the code current http://pastebin.com/ReTukFTW and this is what it looks like right now http://asdfghjklbnmqwertyuiop.tumblr.com/

Comment: The masonry is now working but the infinite scroll isn't. From what I can see, I'm not missing anything. pastebin.com/eyxMAghX htp://asdfghjklbnmqwertyuiop.tumblr.com @riverbell